# Which is faster between a list comprehension and using the list()

Tags: python

Trying to create a list of items using one of these methods:

```
from pathlib import Path

list_comprehension = [item for item in Path('.').iterdir()]    

list_method = list(Path('.').iterdir())
```

Which is faster and how do I check for speed.

Comment: try it like import time; start = time.time();list_comprehension = [item for item in Path('.').iterdir()];end=time.time()-start;print(end)

Comment: Use `timeit` to answer your own question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `timeit` module to achieve it.

```
import timeit

first = """
from pathlib import Path

list_comprehension = [item for item in Path('.').iterdir()]
"""

second = """
from pathlib import Path

list_method = list(Path('.').iterdir())
"""

print(timeit.timeit(stmt=first, number=10000)) 
# 1.0698672000000329
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=second, number=10000))
# 1.0508478000000423
```

[image]

Comment: which python are you using that both the results are almost same?

Comment: @argo python3.6.4, maybe it is related to the machine?

Comment: Thats interesting. can you provide your machine specs?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to check the time

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now()
list_comprehension = [item for item in Path('.').iterdir()]
print(datetime.now()- start_time)
start_time = datetime.now()
list_method = list(Path('.').iterdir())
print(datetime.now()- start_time)
```

EDIT:
You should use *timeit* for better result

```
import timeit

list_comprehension = '''
from pathlib import Path
a = [item for item in Path('.').iterdir()]'''

list_method = ''' 
from pathlib import Path
a = list(Path('.').iterdir())'''

print(timeit.timeit(list_comprehension, number=1000))
# 0.10110808495664969
print(timeit.timeit(list_method, number=1000))
# 0.05479578400263563
```